# Clone Windows from one SSD to larger SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd

My Windows SSD is becoming to small (128GB) and I cannot find any files that I can delete safely. So I bought a 1TB drive and would like to copy my Windows to the larger drive. I have a lot of software and configs and would very much like to not having to setup everything again (Yes I do have backsups which I could youse if everything fails).

Is it possible to use a took like [dd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) to copy Windows from one drive to another?

Or could I use Hardware (with offline-copy function [like](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07429D73L)) to copy the Windows from one SSD to another and then enlarge the partition?

Comment: Depending on your SSD the manufacturer may provide a tool to do this for you. I know Samsung do.

Comment: It is indeed possible.  You can use your favorite software to clone the SSD.  There are numerous questions with very detailed answers.  Which methods have you tried?  Windows tools work best to clone a disk containing Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use AOMEI partition assistant to clone windows [here](https://www.diskpart.com/free-partition-manager.html)